# SSRS No Query Designer is Available

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, mdx, sql-data-tools

I just created a data source  and now I'm adding a data set. I'm using a dataset that is embedded in my report and then I go click on **Query Designer...** and it tells me **No cube can be found**. I click okay and then it tells me **No Query Designer is Available**. Every time I click on **Query Designer...** again, it just goes straight to the **No Query Designer is Available** window.

I looked around for some answers, and some people said that the cube's visibility might be set to false in its properties. However, I checked and it was true. I don't know what to do anymore.

Is there any way I can get this MDX Query Designer window to open? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you managed to fix this problem, but when it happened for me it turned out to be a permissions issue with my data source.

I'll put this as an answer here just in case it helps anyone else out - I found the cube visibility answers quite misleading (although obviously it has helped some people).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this same problem.

I had an embedded datasource defined that connected to my cube. I temporarily created another dataset, selected to embed this dataset in my report, selected the embedded datasource and then attempted to use the Query Designer. It worked for this new dataset. So I then cancelled the creation of the new dataset, went back to the old non-working dataset and was able now open the Query Designer window